# Pick a random random from a list. If it's not the chosen one, pick another one.

Tags: c#, list, random

I have this Guess the number game. The user thinks of a number and the computer will guess it. I have this code but the thing is, every attempt that computer makes there's a chance that the random number will repeat. I would like to know how to create a random list, the computer will pick a number from the list, if it's not correct I would like to have that number deleted so it will not be picked up again. I am new in this field so I would really appreciate any help.

```
private void btnStartTheGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int guessTheNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberGuess.Text);
    DialogResult dialogResult;
    do
    {
        Random newNumberGenerator = new Random();
        number = newNumberGenerator.Next(0, 10);
        dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is number" + number.ToString() + " you are thinking about?", "Answer the question!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No);

    MessageBox.Show("Congratulation! You guessed the number!!");       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short but complete program which does as you require (I have used a console application rather than forms):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dialogResult = "";
    bool[] alreadyGuessed = new bool[10];
    int guesses = 0;

    Random newNumberGenerator = new Random();
    do
    {
        int number = newNumberGenerator.Next(0, 10);
        if (!alreadyGuessed[number])
        {
            guesses++;
            alreadyGuessed[number] = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Are you thinking of the number " + number.ToString() + "?")
            dialogResult = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    while (dialogResult.ToUpper() != "Y" && guesses < 10);

    if (dialogResult.ToUpper() == "Y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I guessed the number!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No numbers left!");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The logic in your original program seemed somewhat backwards; it wasn't clear whether it was the user or the computer doing the guessing. This program assumes that you are thinking of a number between 0 and 9 (inclusive) and leaving the computer to try to guess it, but you can obviously adapt it to your needs. I have also omitted any validation logic.

**EDIT**: As Tarec correctly points out, this doesn't extend to very large number sets. To do that you'd need a proper shuffling algorithm like this:

```
public static void Shuffle(int[] array)
{
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        int j = random.Next(i);
        int temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Then you could change your program to this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dialogResult = "";
    int size = 10;

    int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, size).ToArray();
    Shuffle(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int number = array[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Are you thinking of the number " + number.ToString() + "?");
        dialogResult = Console.ReadLine();
        if (dialogResult.ToUpper() == "Y")
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (dialogResult.ToUpper() == "Y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I guessed the number!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No numbers left!");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now you can change 'size' to whatever you like and the program will work correctly. This is probably overkill for the original poster's needs, though.

Comment: It's not optimal solution. It non-deterministic, because you're running your loop until all random numbers have been used, which is wrong. In some pesimistic variant for last digit you'd on each iteration you'd have a chance of 1/10th to actually hit the correct one. Imagine you're running it against 1000 or a 1 000 000 numbers instead of 10 and you're doomed.

Comment: Of course. But we aren't running against 1,000 or 1,000,000 numbers, we're running against 10. This wasn't intended to be an extensible solution, but it does solve the OP's specific problem. (Also, changing to a million numbers (with automatic checking) runs in about three seconds, so I think 'doomed' is a little exaggerated!)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to @Tarec for making me do it properly!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToList();
DialogResult dialogResult;
Random newNumberGenerator = new Random();
do
{
    int index = newNumberGenerator.Next(0, randomNumbers.Count);
    dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is number" + randomNumbers[index] + " you are thinking about?", "Answer the question!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if(dialogResult==DialogResult.No)
    {
        randomNumbers.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think your answer still allows for duplicate entries to be selected. (Plus I don't think `List<int> randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);` compiles)

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I suppose he want to also remove guessed number from those randomNumbers ;-) Otherwise, it looks ok.

Comment: It's my fault, I forgot about removing used item obviously. And ofcourse dialogResult object has to be declared before the loop. Also this method does not check whether there are any numbers left, user could easily just answet "No" 10 times and then it'll crash on `randomNumbers[index]` call.

Comment: @Tarec You should declare dialogResult before loop.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code by adding an array of number to be chosen. Then I random only the index of the array. If the number if not correct, the number is removed from the array and redo again.

```
int guessTheNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberGuess.Text);
DialogResult dialogResult;
ArrayList numberList = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
   numberList.Add(i);
int length = index.Count;
do
{
   Random newNumberGenerator = new Random();
   index = newNumberGenerator.Next(length);
   dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is number" + numberList[index].ToString() + " you are thinking about?", "Answer the question!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   if( dialogResult == DialogResult.No) 
   {
      numberList.RemoveAt(index);
      length = length - 1;
      if(length == 0)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("No number left!!");  
          return;
      }
   }
}while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No);
MessageBox.Show("Congratulation! You guessed the number!!");
```